Endeca - Combine data from two record stores
I want my search results to return data from two data stores.
For example, I have to record sources ProductCatalog and ArticleRespository, I want to get data from both the record sources.
Added the record filter as OR(record.source:ArticleRepository,,record.source:ProductCatalog)
MDEX is taking the right filter but no data is returned in response.
When I give one data source at a time, data is returned from that datasource correctly.
But I need data from both record sources.

Could we provide the full query reaching to the mdex from dgraph logs? Also, have you tried alternative syntax or use the OR record filter with another attribute to check that it works?

@PanagiotisStoupos actually the filter worked, I misread the response data.
